# Python-based password tracker (or dictionary)

Tags: python, encryption, passwords

Where we work we need to remember about 10 long passwords which need to change every so often. I would like to create a utility which can potentially save these passwords in an encrypted file so that we can keep track of them.

I can think of some sort of dictionary `passwd = {'host1':'pass1', 'host2':'pass2'}`, etc, but I don't know what to do about encryption (absolutely zero experience in the topic).

So, my question is really two questions:

1. Is there a Linux-based utility which lets you do that?
2. If you were to program it in Python, how would you go about it?

A perk of approach two, would be for the software to update the `ssh` public keys after the password has been changed (you know the pain of updating ~15 tokens once you change your password).

As it can be expected, I have zero control over the actual network configuration and the management of `scp` keys. I can only hope to provide a simple utility to me an my very few coworkers so that, if we need to, we can retrieve a password on demand.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to checkout ecryptfs. It should be available for any Linux OS.
On Ubuntu, setting it up is as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
ecryptfs-setup-private
```

This creates a directory for encrypted files, typically called ~/.Private.
To use it:

```
mount -t ecryptfs ~/.Private ~/Private
```

This mounts the encrypted files from ~/.Private at the mount point ~/Private.
You can read/write the plain text files in ~/Private.

```
umount ~/Private
```

updates the encrypted files in ~/.Private and removes ~/Private.

See these links

- [home page](https://launchpad.net/ecryptfs)

  [linux journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9400)

  [tutorial](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/Ecryptfs/)

  [another tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory)

for more information.

Comment: Thank you, this approach may be what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes.  Take a look at [KeePass](http://www.keepassx.org/).
2. I wouldn't program a utility like this in Python, because there are available open source tools already.  Furthermore, I would have concerns about protecting the unencrypted passwords as they were processed by a Python program.

Hope that helps.

Comment: KeePass seems to be a Windows application; Python can work with encrypted hashes.

Comment: @Arrieta - Thanks - I mistyped the URL.  I was trying to point to the Linux port of KeePass.  I've corrected it now.

Comment: I'm voting this answer up because I agree that an already-existing program should be used here.  I'm not endorsing KeePass in particular, as I have not used it.  Asking about password managers on serverfault or superuser might yield more alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

On first i think you can change passwords on md5 of this passwords..
it will give more safety.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to use `hashlib`, but I don't know of a solid approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) or [AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axcrypt/) -- both are Open Source solutions. I'll echo Mox's concerns about the unencrypted PWs.

Of course you could also follow [Bruce Schneier's](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/06/write_down_your.html) advice about password protection...